Literal type hint unavailable outside of the __init__ method
I am using VScode 1.91.1. It seems like it doesn't want to recognize Literal outside of the __init__ method.
Is there a way to have the right type throughout the class?
class MyDict(TypedDict):
    my_var: Literal["a", "b"]

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, my_dict: MyDict):
        self.my_var = my_dict["my_var"] # hovering over `my_var` here shows Literal["a", "b"]

    def other_method(self):
        self.my_var # hovering over it here shows "str"


I don't think you are using Mypy, but rather Pyright via Pylance. That said, what is your question, then? Do you want to know how to type hint the attribute, or are you interested in why the type checker works that way?

yes, I'd like to have the right type on the attribute

You need to have my_var: Literal["a", "b"] directly inside MyClass, or type hint the attribute assignment (self.my_var: Literal["a", "b"] = my_dict["my_var"]). I'm sure this has been asked before; let me find a good dupe.

yes, that works, but it feels like a hack. why doesn't the type propagate to the rest of the class? it recognizes its being a str well enough

It's interesting that PyRight drops the literalness in other_method, when the assignment from my_dict["my_var"] is the only information available to infer any type for self.my_var.

@AnotherSherlock Well, since you didn't give it an explicit hint, it had to guess, and its guesses can't always be correct. There's nothing hacky about the solution I showed you; the former is even preferred.

To be clear, you should annotate self.my_var instead of relying on its type being inferred by the assignment. __init__ is one way to initialize an instance of MyClass; its arguments should not be the source of ground truth.

fair enough. thank you

Funnily enough, all highly upvoted questions about type hinting instance attributes I could find are about comparing the two syntax: Type Hints Convention for Instance Variables Python, Type annotating instance attributes: in init or body?, Python class members type hinting.

Wow. Yes, I fully agree that explicit typing is better anyway, but this is super weird. Consider asking Eric in a Pyright ticket (here) about the "why". Reproduces in playground: https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoAqiApgCYAiSAxjADRQAySMxIAhgDYBQXVHbAZwFQAsnEo0AFEQRkJMAJQAuLlDVQIcAPoA3NiCWNmrTgG0ARG3P1zAI3MBdHn0HCxAYX5CV6qKWLAUFpaqMzBkgLEHMD0mlqk1DCGYvLKqr7qkdEAdHF6IFAAvBraCTQWefqOUADEUAAWYDqsqBhNrFAABpUgnQ2sxFACjQDuwkws7BwWVjb2ThnqIMTNnFrwshFRwLna%2BQrpi4d%2BAVBgMPWsWhDEF2CkW9Fpi2rLqxzrJI87PQdAA

Another closely related question: mypy: base class has no attribute x, how to type hint in base class. I voted to close, but you can decide if this is a suitable duplicate.

You need to hint the attribute in MyClass too
class MyClass:
    my_var: Literal["a", "b"]

    def __init__(self, my_dict: MyDict):
        self.my_var = my_dict["my_var"] # hovering over `my_var` here shows Literal["a", "b"]

    def other_method(self):
        self.my_var # hovering over it here now shows Literal["a", "b"]

This is because python typecheckers will not assume that a variable or an attribute has a Literal type unless you explicitely type it so, so it gets cast to str
